# ubuntu doesn't boot without flash drive

Tags: boot, filesystem, boot-partition

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my Netbook. I had to use a flash key and during the installation i tried putting Ubuntu on a separate partition, but it kept showing a `no root file system is defined` error.

I didn't really know what i could do to fix it, so i decided to install it alongside Windows. I have a windows7 installation, which works perfectly fine. So the installation goes through perfectly and i give both OS's 40 Gigs of space. The comp restarts and NOTHING!

The computer boots directly into Windows.
During the install it said i am supposed to be prompted at boot, and nothing happened. Ubuntu partitioned the `C:` drive, but this partition doesn't show up in Windows. If i boot using the flash drive, it shows the partition with the Ubuntu installation. I tried reinstalling, but now i don't get the prompt to asking me to install Ubuntu.

Really confused ..

Comment: It's possible Grub was installed to the flash drive. I had this happen once several years ago and the computer would not boot unless the flash drive was attached, even though I had another system installed on the hard drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two disk drives and the boot loader was installed to the wrong drive.  Either tell your BIOS to boot from the other drive, or reinstall, and make sure you direct grub to the correct drive.