# Netbook does not boot

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, boot-failure

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 via USB-stick on my EEE PC 1005HA. It booted fine from the hdd with the USB plugged in. If I remove the USB it won't boot from the hdd. When I plug the USB back in, it boots from the hdd just fine but it won't let me boot from the stick even when I select it in the BIOS. I've never experienced something like this. Without the USB plugged in, I just get a blinking underscore and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arno, this link might lead you to a solution. Good luck.

[Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Answer (score 0):

You probably wrote the bootloader to the USB flash drive. Install again and make sure you set the bootloader to be installed on the HDD.