# Grub is installed on the USB drive

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

I tried to install Ubuntu 12. 04 using USB on HP pavilion dv4 which has Windows 7 home premium. The installation went smooth, but after rebooting it directly booted into Windows 7. When I inserted the USB device it showed the grub menu. I suppose the boot loader got installed on the USB device.

Can any one give me a solution to this?

Comment: You mean USB Pendrive? What you had in the USB? An Ubuntu ISO?  What option did you choose: 1. Install with Win. 2. Install alone. or what? What was its previous size and post-installation?

Comment: possibly this, http://askubuntu.com/q/125494/47291

Answer (score 0):

From your booted Ubuntu system, open a terminal, then use the following commands to install grub to the internal drive :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX

sudo update-grub
```

Replacing `sdX` with the actual drive, which will probably be `sda`, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.