# Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit "unable to find medium with live filesystem" AFTER normal install

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, filesystem

So, I got a new computer (64 bit quad core yada yada).

pulled my Ubuntu SSD drive from old machine, installed it into new machine.

(my intention here is to have Ubuntu installed on the 120G SSD, Win7 on the main drive)

downloaded 64 bit Ubuntu, burned it to a disk.

rebooted with Live CD, installed Ubuntu to the SSD drive, had no problems

rebooted again, got the grub menu, selected Ubuntu

after a minute i got this -> "unable to find medium with live filesystem"

booting into windows, explorer doesnt even see the SSD. Device manager sees it though. I assume this is because its formatted with ext4.

so, The liveCD saw the SSD just fine, installed fine, but when i try to boot ubuntu, i get the error above, heeellllpppp!

UPDATE: small update. Windows did a software update that apparently wiped out my grub, so I guess grub was installed on the main drive.  I reinstalled Ubuntu (again) on the SSD drive but, still no joy with booting from it. same error message as above.

Comment: i've no idea.  how/where could i find out?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two drives, one for Windows (lets call it `sdX`) and one for Ubuntu (call it `sdY`, the SSD), then the easiest way to get both working is:

- Install GRUB in `sdY` (the SSD with Ubuntu).
- Change boot order in BIOS to boot first from the `sdY` (the SSD with
  Ubuntu) drive.
- Boot Ubuntu and open a terminal by pressing
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo
  update-grub`

The last step should find the Windows in the `sdX` and update Grub accordingly and from next boot,you should be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Based on comments below: This looks like UEFI problem. Try BIOS legacy mode (as opposed to EFI). However, this may make Windows unbootable or worse, install both Windows and Ubuntu again. Use caution.

Comment: Basically just did that, and still not working.
I changed boot order to the SSD first, did a fresh install of Ubuntu onto that drive, reboot and at grub prompt select Ubuntu. I got the Ubuntu loading screen with the 5 dots thats change color, after a couple minutes i got the same error "unable to find medium with live filesystem".

Comment: Hahve you tried boot-repair? the details are here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in.

Comment: just tried it, no joy.
trying it again...

Comment: well, i seem to be making some progress...
Now it loads grub in a different resolution (lol).
I get the Ubuntu loading screen, then below that an error saying "The disk drive for /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present"
"Continue to wait, press S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery"

Comment: This looks like UEFI problem. Try BIOS legacy mode (as opposed to EFI). However, this may make Windows unbootable or worse, install both Windows and Ubuntu again. Use caution.

Comment: spot on! disabling uefi worked!

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted so that others with similar problem can benefit from it.