# Can't start ubuntu without USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Installed ubuntu with USB boot, but when I restarted, the laptop was unable to detect it on he HDD. When I boot from the USB everything works as it should though (it's not the pre-installation screen), but I installed it on the HDD. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you installed GRUB on the pendrive instead of on the hard disk.

Boot through your USB drive, open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and type `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/`. You'll get a list of drives of the sort /sda1 /sda2  or /sdb1 etc.

Identify the hard disk where Ubuntu is installed. If it is say sda4, in the terminal type: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` without the final number.

Shutdown, remove the pendrive and turn on again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with To Do. It sounds like something is up with your GRUB.

This help page is about recovering GRUB after  windows install but should be useful in correctly installing the GRUB in any situation:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Hope this helps. Take care.