# Ubuntu doesn´t start after installation

Tags: 12.04, startup

This is my first time running Ubuntu on a PC. I have made a bootfile on my USB and the installation goes without any problems. When the installation is finished it says the computer needs to restart. Here is where the problems starts:

I just get an error message that looks like this:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
```

If I restart the computer from the USB stick it ask if I want to install Ubuntu in parallel with Ubuntu. So I assume that there is an installation on my PC.

I have tried both 12.04 and 13.10 with the same result. I have tried to wait and to write exit under the error message but it will not start.

Comment: It appears that there was a problem with your installation, such that the USB is required.  This is not an uncommon problem, check this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 13.10) I had left the BIOS to boot up on CD/DVD. Changing this back to HD fixed it (well at least for the last 2 attempts!).

Well .... it failed the first time I tried it next day! So, presumably the BIOS is not the cure.