# Every time ubuntu need usb drive to run

Tags: 12.04

I am new to the Ubuntu.
I have installed the ubuntu 12.04 from the usb drive. But it needs the usb drive every time to open and run. 
Please suggest me a solution to overcome.

Comment: please give full specifications and also have you dual booted and what do you mean by everytime dosen't a grub menu (a boot menu) comes out to select operating system??

Comment: there is no option for selecting the OS. i had install the ubuntu only

Comment: try reinstalling

Comment: i had try many times,

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and type following command

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

this will write a MBR and install grub
by the way grub is a boot controller which allows you to boot to multiple os 
for more info read this

[Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Comment: I got the following error while run this command: /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
What is this mean

Comment: fist of all have you updated system??

Comment: this means you have to get the address of the partition where you have installed ubuntu

Comment: so how to get the address of the partition?

Comment: open dashboard and type disks you will get the disks and the major partiton where ubuntu is installed is the first one and also it is of ext4 file system type actually /dev/sda is the first one the primary partition of you HDD