# Fresh install 14.04, things start crashing

Tags: 14.04

I have a fresh install of 14.04 on a new laptop (toshiba z30) and I've been following the "top things to do after install ubuntu" style websites.

Issues started not long after installing the "unity tweak tool", before I've made any tweaks. I've seen a few suggestions but due to the culmination of issues I'm kinda stuck

- Unity tweak fonts were untouched, though I've tried restoring defaults. Editing font crashes the tool.
- Ubuntu Software center crashes on open
- Terminal does not open

So I'm a littl unsure what I can do to start rectifying the sitation - I'm not sure how I can uninstall stuff in an attempt to isolate the issue?

**An update** - I must have been in some post-installation limbo. I reset the computer, and all the installation, file creation, settings etc I made have been lost. I seem to be back at step one, which is fine - but I'm curious if anyone can suggest what might have happened? I installed ubuntu from bootable USB

Comment: Looking at your comment above(which you should have actually posted in your question's description by editing it) [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in) might be your issue...

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'm used to the Oracle forums format. After Ubuntu installed I removed the USB but didn't restart until I started getting issues. Now it boots up fine so I imagine the install process installed Grub for me. I don't see I need to do anything else? I still wonder where my initial configurations went...