# black screen startup. Try Ubuntu now asks for password

Tags: system-installation, login-screen

So I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop that I just tried to fully install Ubuntu 14.10 (I think, most recent) on.

When I originally clicked Try, everything would load as expected.

So I tried to install but when I go to restart laptop with no USB in I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. I read somewhere one possibility may be the grub has installed on the USB [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

I try to restart laptop with USB in and select Try, but now when Ubuntu loads I get prompted for a password. This didn't happen before. I put in the password of choice (easy to remember as it is the username) but I get password not recognised error.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself.

I attempted to reinstall again but this time chose which partition to install on and was able to select the boot loader location.

Seems strange that with a fresh install from USB, the boot loader was not installed on the hard drive.