# Unable to boot Windows without flash drive in computer

Tags: grub2, windows, startup, restore, busybox

I recently attempted to install ubuntu 14.04 on a usb flash drive so I can use it on the go. I burned the iso to a cd and booted it by doing try ubuntu without installing and then I clicked install ubuntu and tried to install to my usb drive.

Now, when I turn on my computer which had windows 8 on it, when the USB flash drive is not in the computer, it gives me this black screen that says

```
GNU GRUB VERSION 2.02 BETA2-9UBUNTU1
MINIMAL BASH LIKE LINE EDITING IS SUPPORTED. 
FOR THE FIRST WORD, TAB LISTS POSSIBLE COMMAND COMPLETITONS.
ANYWHERE ELSE TAB LISTS POSSIBLE DEVICE OR FILE COMPLETIONS 
GRUB>_
```

and it does not let me do anything except type things  in the command line.

The only way I can boot my Windows is by putting the USB flash drive in and choosing Windows Boot Manager in the purple options menu with

```
Ubuntu 
Advanced Options for Ubuntu 
Windows Boot Manager
System Settings
```

I want to be able to boot my old Windows without having the USB in like I did before. This is a big mistake I made and I don't know how to fix it.

I am able to go into both Ubuntu and Windows ONLY WHEN THE USB IS IN THE COMPUTER and this is not like it was before. Before I could simply go into Windows automatically by powering the device on but now it makes me put the flash drive in!

Comment: Was this pre-installed Windows 8, so it is UEFI, or your install of Windows booting in BIOS mode? And then did you install Ubuntu in BIOS mode to flash drive or in UEFI mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Answer (score 0):

These steps should solve your problem, taken straight from https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-1

Boot problems with Windows 8, can often be solved in the following manner.

1. If you don't have an install DVD of Windows 8, then download a free evaluation copy of Windows 8 at Microsoft itself:
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx

If you don't have a Windows Live account, you need to create one for this. It's free, and it's not necessary to fill out your real name.

2. Burn the iso on a DVD. That can be done in the same way as with an iso of Ubuntu.
3. Boot your computer from the Windows 8 DVD and select:
   Repair your computer (down left, do NOT select "Install now") - Troubleshoot - Advanced options - Command Prompt
4. Now type the following command line (note the required space between "bootrec" and "/fixmbr"):

   `bootrec /fixmbr`

Press Enter.

Then:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

Press Enter.

Then:

```
bootrec /scanos
```

Press Enter.

Then:

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Press Enter. Confirm the action by typing y and press Enter again.

5. Remove the DVD and turn your computer off (press the hardware power button for five seconds).
6. Turn your computer on again and press the key for one-time boot changes. For Acer computers this key is usually F12, but this differs for each brand.
7. Select "Windows Boot Manager". After a short while you should be presented again with the (in)famous tiles of Windows 8.
8. If you have a dual boot computer, with Linux alongside Windows, then you might need to restore Grub, in order to make your Linux bootable again.