# Cannot boot ubuntu without usb plugged in and cannot use the usual way to install grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu automatically using a jump flash, however it cannot boot without usb. I tried the way of typing "`sudo grub-install/dev/sda`", and it just doesn't work! Also I am still confused where I install the grub2. Hope someone can help me. The terminal screen is showed as followed:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa62b4079

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 7858 MB, 7858028544 bytes
90 heads, 30 sectors/track, 5684 cylinders, total 15347712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          24    15347711     7673844    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install/dev/sda
sudo: grub-install/dev/sda: command not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space between `grub-install` and `/dev/sda`:

```
sudo grub-install/dev/sda
```

Hence `sudo` looks for `grub-install/dev/sda` as command. Command should follow these patterns:

```
sudo [sudo-option] command [command-arguments]
```

So in your case:

- Command is `grub-install`
- Command argument just one which is `/dev/sda` (device node)

BTW, To fix the boot you need to mount your root partition then add as `--root-directory` option. Example:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/username/rootpartiton /dev/sda
```

**References:**

Open terminal from dash or using <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+t</kbd>, then run these to see the manuals

- `man sudo`
- `man grub-install`

To quit, press <kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I found the real problem is that the ubuntu installation is incomplete, and the pc asked me to restart for new installation. And I did as it told me, however the installation was still the one that I have installed, I even chose to reinstall overwrite the previous ubuntu, it still showed the installation was incomplete. Appreciate for you help.

Comment: Ok, it is an XY problem. I see you've created another post. I flag this one to be closed as **a problem that can't be reproduced**