# Unable to Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing - no drives shown

Tags: boot, lubuntu, uefi

After installing Lubuntu, I got the `No bootable device` error, and after searching the net for a solution, tried to set the `Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing` option as instructed, but it does not show me any drives. The Information screen in the bios setup shows me HDD0, but the Security screen that's supposed to let me select the efi file shows nothing, unless I insert the USB. I set the supervisor password after installation, and I thought this may be a reason, and installed it all over again. But it's still showing me nothing. I am sure the installation was done on the hard disk because all previous boot options are gone (as I wanted).

What can be the problem? P.S. I am new to Linux.

Edit:

I have tried turning off secure boot, but it did not help.

I have checked and there is one partition with file system `lvm2 pv` with flags `boot` and `lvm`.

It's an Acer Aspire E 15 (E5-575-50RM) that came with Linpus and had no GUI. I have installed lubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.

I did not use any software to create the USB since my Windows XP is damaged and files are missing or corrupted. I used EaseUS Partition Master to format the USB as FAT32 and then copied the extracted ISO files to it, then marked the single partition as active.

Comment: Have you tried turning off Secure Boot? Have you tried booting that USB and verifying there are partitions on the hard drive? Don't answer as a comment. Just edit your question to add that info. While you are at it, include computer model and O.S.  version.

Comment: @jpezz I've added the info

Comment: It appears you do NOT have an O.S. installed on the hard disk. Be sure when you boot from the USB Live that you tell it you really want the info written to hard disk.

Comment: If you have LVM, did you choose the advanced volume management system? Not recommended for newer users, but required if you want full drive encryption. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: i did not choose encryption, just LVM. nor did it ask me to specify where it should be written to. but since the original OS is gone, I'm certain it wrote to the HDD. would installing it without LVM fix it? is the file system the problem? should it be FAT32 for the bios to detect it?

Comment: If it works with the USB plugged in consider reading this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this tutorial:
https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/

At the end of the setting, in the booting device menu, select the bootloader and move it at the top of the list and that's all.