# Ubuntu only boots with the live-USB connected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu using a LiveUSB, I was unable to boot into Ubuntu.
I can boot up Ubuntu when I have my LiveUSB in, as in when the live session starts, I restart and am able to login to my Ubuntu account. When I remove the LiveUSB, it doesn't work, it just boots to Windows 10 (I'm dual-booting). I tried switching the boot order, but I couldn't find any option related to Ubuntu or GRUB. I tried boot repair, but it still didn't work. The link it told me to copy is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ys3S9tQgRk

I'm new to  Linux and Ubuntu so I don't know what to do. Hopefully, you guys can find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Did you make note of *where* you installed Ubuntu?  You need to enter your firmware settings (BIOS) and select the volume that contains your Ubuntu installation.  How are you certain that the installation completed successfully?  Did you choose the "install alongside Windows" option?

Comment: @Nmath, for the installation process, I looked at multiple tutorials, and they told me to select the 'something else' option (using partitions). I used that. I don't know if it installed properly or not, and if I change the boot order, it still only boots Windows. The options I can use are: Windows Boot Manager, USB HDD (Changes to my LiveUSB when it's plugged in), USB FDD, two network options, and USB CDROM.

Comment: If the option was offered, *take it*, since it will automate the process for you. Since you don't remember what you did, I suggest that you start over. Take notes so you can give us information in case it's not successful again. Tip: it's best if you have *unpartitioned free space* before starting the installer so you get the automated option.  Also, if Windows is installed as UEFI, you need to boot the installer as UEFI. When booting the USB, if you see a mauve/purple screen with a keyboard and accessibility icon at the bottom, you've booted wrong - check your BIOS settings

Comment: Alright, I'll try using the install alongside windows option. Will my previous installation affect my new installation?

Comment: I would just delete the partition for Ubuntu prior to the installation using the Disks app in the live session.  That will give you the unpartitioned free space. Of course be careful and don't remove the wrong one(s)

Comment: Alright. For the partitions I want to delete, as in the partition I used for Ubuntu previously, will it be labelled as Ubuntu or will they have a different name in the Disks app?

Comment: It's your hard drive! We can try to help identify partitions if you post a screenshot of them in the Disks app.  Once you figure out what's what, you should make note of it someplace.  Don't delete your EFI (shared boot) partition and don't delete any partitions used by Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Answer (score 0):

Disable Fast startup in windows ([see this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html))

Also check if your windows OS was installed in UEFI or Legacy BIOS mode ([see this](https://pureinfotech.com/check-bios-uefi-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Open%20Start%20on%20Windows%2010,section%2C%20find%20the%20BIOS%20Mode.)). You may need to set the BIOS boot mode to UEFI to get into Ubuntu if Windows was installed in Legacy mode (which might mean switching the bios mode every time you want to switch between OS's).

edit: Also see if you can disable legacy and only boot UEFI in the BIOS

Comment: I disabled the Fast Startup in windows. Windows was installed on UEFI, does that mean I need to switch to Legacy to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: No, you want both to be UEFI (at least that's how I did it). Still no Ubuntu option in the boot order of the BIOS?