# Need help booting from SSD

Tags: boot, usb, ssd

I need help.  This is my first time with Ubuntu. I had a hard drive crash, and thought this would be a good time to switch over. Having said that, launched into this with no former knowledge.

I bought a 500GB WD Blue SSD.  I will probably by a bigger one for storage later.

I completely removed any old hard drives. No trace of Windows.

I started by downloading Ubuntu iso, then flashing it 16GB Sandisk USB key. I also used Rufus and another app prior to.

I plugged the USB key in, had the BIOS start at the USB key. It unpacked the ISO, and loaded Ubuntu.

It appears that it has made 2 different operating systems: (1) for the USB key, which works just fine, but is limited, and(2) Ubuntu operating on the SSD.

So, if I shut off the computer, if I leave the USB key in, it starts back up.

If I take the USB key out, it does not see the SSD as having a boot record.  The BIOS does see the SSD, and but when it boots up without the USB key, it acts like the SSD is not there and is looking for a boot record on some other device.

One thing. to note, and I am not sure if it is important, is that at first, I could not even write to the SSD, but after doing the nsftfix and fsck, between those two, something fixed it, and I was able to copy files on to the SSD.

I appreciate any help that you can give me.  This is really holding me up.  I am OK with getting into terminal and drafting the lines, I just need step by step.  It seems like a simple thing, and what I have reviewed, this seems to be a pretty common problem but without easy answers. Speaking for myself, its this kind of frustration that turns people off.  Its a matter of frustration and time. But, I do like the outlay of Ubuntu, to me its more like Apple GUI than Windows, and I am tired of MS and what it stands for.

For the record I did download the Boot Record fixer app, but have not known what to do with it yet.

Thanks for any help in advance.

RTW

Comment: I do not understand unpacking ISO. Rufus should have done that onto 16GB flash drive and then you boot system in UEFI mode & do install onto SSD. Is not explicit about UEFI boot, but shows many install screens. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Many systems require UEFI settings, many defaults are set for Windows. What brand/model system? Some also need UEFI firmware update. And even new SSD often need firmware updates. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467629&p=14061395#post14061395

Comment: I just said unpacking the ISO meaning it started installing from the flash drive. I do not have any option for UEFI mode in the BIOS.  I have not even seen anything that UEFI.  Dell XPS 8300.

Comment: If from 2011, it then may be BIOS only. It was about then that vendors started converting BIOS to UEFI even with some Windows 7 systems. I still used gpt partitioning back in 2011, but had to have a tiny 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. I used gparted to do that.  Does BIOS show SSD? If not then that is a major issue. Also how much RAM? if 4GB or less, you may prefer a lighter weight flavor. Ubuntu assumes newer systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I use Kubuntu which is more mid-weight.

Comment: 8 Gigabyte Ram, and the BIOS does show the SSD, proper identifies, everything.

Comment: Just to see what is where: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Comment: I tried the install that Karel posted.  I think it revealed what the issue is as the response stated: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.

Comment: So, it looks like there is no boot partition on SSD at all. what do I do from here? Also, I will try to get a boot report summary.

Comment: Boot Summary Report  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fhrjzyvzCr/

Comment: MacEFI detected. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

Comment: I also get that message when I try and get into Boot Repair

Comment: So when I just now tried to placed GRUB in the MBR on SDA (WD Blue SSD) I got the MacEFI detected error, about "Please disable BIOS-comptibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware" and I don't have a clue where that is, I do not see it in the BIOS.

Comment: Also, it looks like the Dell SPX 8300 is a Legacy BIOS if that helps.